# How to redirect to a base route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have an issue in laravel routing ,

I am able to go to the following routes independently:

```
*localhost/jmeercat/public/home*

*localhost/jmeercat/public/manageProject/newlycreatedproject*
```

But if I am on the route `*localhost/jmeercat/public/manageProject/newlycreatedproject*`
and click on home page link I am redirected to *localhost/jmeercat/public/manageProject/home* path instead of *localhost/jmeercat/public/home*.

I am using `return Redirect::to('home')` method.

Comment: How is your home route setup?

Comment: how do you provide your "home page link"? Please give more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Laravel documentation on Named Routes - http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Named routes make referring to routes when generating redirects or URLs more convenient. You may specify a name for a route like so:

```
Route::get('/home', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@home'));
```

You may use the route's name when generating URLs or redirects:

```
$url = URL::route('home');

$redirect = Redirect::route('home');
```